# How to change Datetime Format in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a DATETIME format like this: '17-09-2019 06:22:00 PM'. I'm trying to use this format to convert '2019-09-17 06:22:00 PM'.

```
datetime.strptime(startingDate, '%y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
```

But I get an error. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You want `startingDate.strftime("%y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")`

Comment: yes. but this is not work for me.

Comment: If staringDate is a string you need to call strptime with the original format then .strftime on it

Comment: "I get an error" is not a problem description. Please include the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Show the error in the question

Comment: i try to save this datetime format but nothing add in system

Comment: `datetime` doesn't have format - you can only use format to generate text with date and time.

Comment: staringDate is post request actually @geckos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input time format is wrong, it should match the string you are putting in.

`"%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p"` becomes `"%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p"`

Notice that the order of the date has changed.

```py
import datetime

startingDate =  "17-09-2019 06:22:00 PM"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(startingDate, "%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
datetime.datetime.strftime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")

# "2019-09-17 06:22:00 PM"
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by add GMT. Do you mean timezone? This can be added using `%Z` or `%z`.

Comment: actually i am using POstgresql when i try to save your solution in database. postgresql datetime store today date. even i select  next day date. and postgresql GMT time zone used.

Comment: This isn't clear from your original question, you should update it to reflect this. How are you trying to add the datetime to postgresql?

Comment: That still doesn't help. Are you using django?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

startingDate = '17-09-2019 06:22:00 PM'
newDate = datetime.strptime(startingDate, '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")
print(newDate)
```

https://repl.it/repls/JuniorPushyLoopfission

Comment: your solution work. but problem is when 1 try to save in db then get today date automatic. even i select next day date.

Comment: Maybe you have some default set on that field? Please add more info about dB structure to the question.